# How to convert SkiaSharp.SkBitmap to Android.Graphics.Bitmap?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, bitmap, skiasharp, skia

I want to convert `PinBitmap` (`SkiaSharp.SkBitmap`) to `Android.Graphics.Bitmap`. I couldn't find online references, I only tried this in the Android project:

```
Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(myView.PinBitmap.Bytes, 0, myView.PinBitmap.Bytes.Length);
```

but the `bitmap` is null.

I'm creating the `PinBitmap` from a SKCanvasView:

```
private void SKCanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    var surface = e.Surface;
    var canvas = surface.Canvas;
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;

    canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 10, 200, new SKPaint() { IsStroke = true, Color = SKColors.Green, StrokeWidth = 10 });
    SKBitmap saveBitmap = new SKBitmap();

    // Create bitmap the size of the display surface
    if (saveBitmap == null)
    {
        saveBitmap = new SKBitmap(info.Width, info.Height);
    }
    // Or create new bitmap for a new size of display surface
    else if (saveBitmap.Width < info.Width || saveBitmap.Height < info.Height)
    {
        SKBitmap newBitmap = new SKBitmap(Math.Max(saveBitmap.Width, info.Width),
                                          Math.Max(saveBitmap.Height, info.Height));

        using (SKCanvas newCanvas = new SKCanvas(newBitmap))
        {
            newCanvas.Clear();
            newCanvas.DrawBitmap(saveBitmap, 0, 0);
        }

        saveBitmap = newBitmap;
    }

    // Render the bitmap
    canvas.Clear();
    canvas.DrawBitmap(saveBitmap, 0, 0);

    var customPin = new CustomPin { PinBitmap = saveBitmap };
    Content = customPin;
}
```

Comment: are you sure the data in PinBitmap is valid and in an image format this is supported by Android.Graphics.Bitmap?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's valid, but I followed [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/saving#saving-finger-paint-art) to save a `SKCanvasView` to a `Bitmap`

Comment: You should probably take the time to verify the data before you waste hours debugging the wrong problem.

Comment: How to verify the data of a Bitmap?

Comment: Write it to a file and use an image editor to validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is easy to do, you just need to have the SkiaSharp.Views NuGet
> package installed. Then, there are extension methods:
>
> ```
> skiaBitmap = androidBitmap.ToSKBitmap(); 
> androidBitmap = skiaBitmap.ToBitmap();
> ```
>
> There are also a few others, like: ToSKImage
> and ToSKPixmap.
>
> NOTE: these all make copies of the pixel data. To avoid memory issue,
> you can dispose of the original as soon as the method returns.

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/294868/#Comment_294868

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert PinBitmap (SkiaSharp.SkBitmap) to Android.Graphics.Bitmap

In Android MainActivity, you could use `AndroidExtensions.ToBitmap` Method to convert PinBitmap to Bitmap.

`AndroidExtensions.ToBitmap` Method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.android.androidextensions.tobitmap?view=skiasharp-views-1.68.1

Install `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms` from NuGet Package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms/

Use the reference.

```
using SkiaSharp.Views.Android;
```

Use the code below.

```
var bitmap = AndroidExtensions.ToBitmap(PinBitmap);
```